# Why the "for each" loop doesn't works like a "for" loop in this example?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I need some help with this code, when i try to show all chars in Java with the "for loop" it's okay, java shows me all, when i do this with the "for each" i have only undefined  symbols

```
char[] chars = new char[65535];
    for (int go = 0; go < chars.length; go++) { // THIS CODE IS OKAY!
        // for (int go : chars) { // **THIS CODE DOESN'T WORKS! WHY??** 
        chars[go] = (char) go; // Change int type to char
    }
    for (char owo : chars) { // Output characters
        System.out.println(owo);
    }
```

Comment: Your chars array doesn't contain anything. In the first example you use the counter of the loop to create/set all possible chars! Since the enhanced for loop doesn't have a counter this obviously won't work and just declaring the type as int shows a misunderstanding of what an enhanced for loop does.

Comment: *"when i try to show all chars in Java with the "for loop" it's okay, java shows me all"* I doubt that. At least with the code you've provided (your first code doesn't print anything and you're doing two different things).

Comment: `for (int go : chars)` is a little strange considering the base type of `chars` is not `int`. Aside from the logic flaw others have pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int go : chars) {
```

Used when you are sure that your array is not empty

```
for (int go = 0; go < chars.length; go++) {
```

Used when you want to get the values of `i`, **0, 1, 2, ...n**

**EDIT**

If that is required to use `for (int go : chars) {` you have to add another variable like this :

```
int i = 0;
for (int go : chars) {
    chars[i] = (char) i;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: So if i need to do this program with the only for-each loop, how is it?

Comment: if you want to use `for (int go : chars) {` you have to add another variable @Ess check my edit

Comment: Why use `int go` when `chars` doesn't have `int` as its base type?

Comment: The for-each loop shown here is bad. It extracts `go` but never uses that variable within the loop. This tells us that that is the wrong approach.

Comment: @LewBloch in your first comment yes you are true, the second this is what the OP ask **So if i need to do this program with the only for-each loop, how is it?** if you can share another solution i will be happy LewBloch

Comment: When you make a down-vote why you don't follow it with a comment please?

Comment: Someone else here already provided that. And to heck with the homework assignment, using a for-each is contraindicated when you don't use the variable. Homework or no homework, it's just plain the wrong thing to do.

Comment: mmmm, ok @LewBloch thank u

Answer (score 0):

nothing in your array, the number 65535 is just the size of the array, it means 
chars[0] to chars[65534]